# How to Restrict multiple login at a time with same user name and password in limited iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a iphone application, and I want to restrict user to only use his login upto 5 different devices simultaneously. when he will try to login on to the 6th device. the login should fail." How can i achieve this functionality in ios using objective c.
thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to pass device UDID along with userName and Password. check it there. if you get more than 5 UUID. give the Alert.

Comment: You are right @ Narendra Pandey...

Comment: Well this device checking part generally we can do at server side. You have to just pass username / password and device id into service and service will recognise how many devices logged in with this id and based on that server will respond so nothing do at client(iOS) side.

Comment: Need a back end support to achieve above funcationality

Comment: okay thanks alot..got it and will inform back team about the concept..

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this through your backend server .

1. when you do login you need to pass device's unique token and store it to server and remove that token with logout. and
2. check in server that if 5 device token is exist in server then 6th login request is failed if arrived .